How to disable scrolling in SfCalendar .Net Maui?

I'm creating a page with a two-month calendar on it. I am using two Syncfusion SfCalendar calendars for this purpose.
I also added my own navigation which is interlinked with the SfCalendar navigation (it is marked in blue), which switches to the next two months and previous months.
But I have a problem, I can't scroll or swipe in SfCalendar itself in both. This causes a bug, because I can swipe to the side and the next month is displayed, which is already present on the screen.
How can I disable this scrolling or swiping?
